# How to run execute_process in cmake with wildcard?

Tags: cmake

Below is the CMakeLists.txt file, that tries to execute terminal command with wildcard character `*.txt`. Currently it gives error `ls: cannot access '*.txt': No such file or directory`. But, when I try to run without the wildcard it runs as expected, ie it lists the files in the current directory.

Is there any way I could use wild cards in execute_process?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(foo)

execute_process(COMMAND ls *.txt
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE curr_out
  ERROR_VARIABLE  curr_out
  )

message(STATUS "${result}  :  ${curr_out}")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html0) one of expansions done by your [shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) *before* the command is executed and it causes `*.txt` to expand to the list of files using special rules.

You have to run the shell to cause `*.txt` to expand.

```
COMMAND sh -c "ls *.txt"
```

Using `file(GLOB tmp "*.txt")` and passing `tmp` would be a more cmake-ish way.

Comment: I also tried with `file(UPLOAD .. ` it also gives error when I try to use wild card.