# CMake execute_process giving no output

Tags: cmake

I am trying to make CMake execute

```
ls -d /usr/local/gasnet/include/*-conduit | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev | cut -d- -f1 | paste -d " "  - - - -
```

and save the result into a variable CONDUITS using the following snippet. However, this defines CONDUITS as an empty string. What is going wrong?

```
      EXECUTE_PROCESS (COMMAND "ls -d" "$ENV{GASNET_HOME}/include/*-conduit"
            COMMAND rev
            COMMAND "cut -d/ -f1"
            COMMAND rev
            COMMAND "cut -d- -f1"
            COMMAND "paste -d" "\" \" - - - -"
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE CONDUITS
        COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT)
```

This is the output from COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT, so it seems the ls command already has empty output.

```
'ls -d' '/usr/local/gasnet/include/*-conduit'
'rev'
'cut -d/ -f1'
'rev'
'cut -d- -f1'
'paste -d' '" " - - - -'
```

Comment: Your quoting looks suspicious. Can you try to remove all quotes but the two that were in the  original command (`paste -d " "  - - - -`)?

Comment: @vre It now tells me "ls: cannot access '/usr/local/gasnet/include/*-conduit': No such file or directory" I guess it does not recognize * as a wildcard? I included the quotes because of the white spaces and special characters as specified [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#quoted-argument). I also tried only quoting arguments, and leaving the commands unquoted, but that gave the same issue.

Comment: If wildcards are involved you need to use `sh -c "ls -d $ENV{GASNET_HOME}/include/*-conduit"`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408751/how-to-run-execute-process-in-cmake-with-wildcard) for a similar example.

Comment: One of the main features and purposes of CMake is to make build instructions platform independent. Putting shell commands into `execute_process` defeats that purpose. Are you sure what your custom command is doing cannot be done with CMake primitives?

Comment: @DevSolar Maybe, but I am building something that makes extensive use of virtual memory management using POSIX functions, so it's not portable anyway.

Comment: Whoops, I misinterpreted `execute_process` as `add_custom_command` in my now-deleted answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run execute\_process in cmake with wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408751/how-to-run-execute-process-in-cmake-with-wildcard)